# Black screen when trying to update graphics drivers of laptop

Tags: laptop, drivers, amd-radeon, display-driver

My brother has a Samsung NP350-V5C with a Intel HD4000 and a AMD radeon 7600M series GPU with a switch. When he received it the switchable graphics weren't working properly: the system only used the Intel so my bro couldn't play games including Batman Arkham City GOTY, a recent gift. So he started Samsung Update wizard and downloaded the latest version available. Then he ran install, so it started to setup things and mess up things since during setup the screen became black, no matter what you would do. After a long while he rebooted its laptop the samsung logo appeared, but after that the screen was black and he couldn't do anything. Sometime mouse cursor would appear but that's all.

I went into safe mode and disabled AMD driver, and the computer could boot normally again. But still couldn't play. We tried to go on AMD and download the official detection wizard, which told us the computer wasn't supported or something like that. I downloaded the official matching  driver directly and i installed it but  I got a black screen while setup and on reboot too. Same problem with Intel's HD drivers.

After I found Leshcatlabs which provided up-to-date drivers which according to them could work. Well, I installed only their 13.12 AMD drivers and it worked!!!!

OK, but now the drivers are outdated so I tried to update them: I went on AMD website and ran the detection tools which worked. I ran the downloaded installer and got black screen. I restored a system restore point and tried leshcatlab's whql latest drivers. I selected the proper Intel graphics driver (the automatic detection selected the wrong one). If I tried to run setup.exe, it would abort and tell us that it wasn't certified or something like that. So I opened Device Manager and updated Intel drivers by selecting the folder where Intel setup.exe was located it started to install, asked me if I'd like to trust the author and installed the driver. The screen blinked a second and the installation succeeded. But when I reboot I still get that black screen!!!!

Comment: Unless the updated AMD driver has a specific performance increase for Batman then I would just leave "well-enough" alone and stick to the 13.12 drivers. If the support is so poor right now then I imagine it will continue to be poor. What did Samsung say regarding the matter?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus now he have a lot of other hand such as batman arkham origins which does not run even in ultra lie

Comment: What is `ultra lie`?

Comment: Sorry, i meant ultra low :)

Comment: An (almost) golden rule with graphics drivers is leave them alone if they're working OK. Also, some laptops actively prevent you from installing generic drivers & insist you use the ones supplied by the lappy manufacturer - til they can no longer be bothered to update them, about 6 months after the lappy was first released.